# gnuplot doesn't follow given timefmt

Tags: gnuplot

My file has data like this:

```
  01:12:27 30000
  01:12:37 30000
  01:12:47 30000
  01:12:57 30000
  ..
  01:18:17 90000
  01:18:27 90000
  01:18:37 90000
  01:18:47 90000
  01:18:57 90000
```

and these are the commands I use to set the X-axis

```
  gnuplot> set xdata time; 
           set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'; 
           set xlabel "time";
```

But the graph has tics on the x -axis as 0, 13:00, 14:00 ...18:00. The graph incorrectly shows that the y-value is valid until 18:00. Also most of the points are concentrated on the leftmost section of the graph. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine, you are just confused about the format of the xaxis tics: Gnuplot uses MM:SS in your case.
You can set the format for the axis with `set format x "%H:%M:%S"` (the format for the axis is independent from the format in the datafile!)

Then, you will notice that your x-axis ranges from 01:12:00 to 01:19:00

And there are also points on the right. They are on the upper border, sou you may have overseen them. Plot `with linespoints` and you'll see it:

[image]